# Having user add multiple Images to SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui

I am practicing with SwiftUI and making a meme maker which has labels that are produced from a textField and can be moved and resized. I also want to be able to do this with images from the users Photo library. I am able to get one image, but if I try and get more it just replaces the first image. I tried having the images added to an array, but then the images will not show up on the memeImageView.

Image property

```
   @State private var image = UIImage()
```

Button

```
Button {
            self.isShowPhotoLibrary = true

        } label: {
            Text("Add Image")
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary) {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: self.$image)
        }
```

MemeUmageView

```
var memeImageView: some View {
    ZStack {
        KFImage(URL(string: meme.url ?? ""))
            .placeholder {
                ProgressView()
            }
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2.5)
        
        ForEach(addedLabels, id:\.self) { label in
            
            DraggableLabel(text: label)
            
        }
        
        DraggableImage(image: image)
        
    }
    .clipped()

}
```

Attempt with using an array. I also tried making three buttons to add up to three images, each as its own property thinking that the initial property was being overridden.

My image array

```
@State private var addedImages = [UIImage?]()
```

Button

```
Button {
    self.isShowPhotoLibrary = true
    addedImages.append(image)

} label: {
    Text("Add Image")
        .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
}.sheet(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary) {
    ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: self.$image)
}

var memeImageView: some View {
        ZStack {
            KFImage(URL(string: meme.url ?? ""))
                .placeholder {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2.5)
            
            ForEach(addedLabels, id:\.self) { label in
                
                DraggableLabel(text: label)
                
            }
            
            ForEach(0..<addedImages.count) { index in
                DraggableImage(image: addedImages[index]!)
            }
            
        }
        .clipped()

    }
```

Where I call MemeImageView.

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            
            memeImageView
            
            ForEach(0..<(meme.boxCount ?? 0)) { i in
                TextField("Statement \(i + 1)", text: $addedLabels[i])
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                    .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.25))
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.endEditing()
                    }

            }
            .padding(.horizontal)

        }.onTapGesture {
            self.endEditing()
        }
        
        
        // Gets a new Image
        Button {
            self.isShowPhotoLibrary = true
            addedImages.append(image)

        } label: {
            Text("Add Image")
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary) {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: self.$image)
        }
        
       
        Spacer()

        // Saves Image
        Button {
            // takes a screenshot and crops it
            if let image = memeImageView.takeScreenshot(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets.top + navBarHeight + 1), size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2.5)) {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // dismisses the view
            }
            
        }
        label: {
            Text("Save image")
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
        }.frame( width: 150, height: 50)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 3)
        )
        
        
        .navigationBarTitle(meme.name ?? "Meme", displayMode: .inline)
        .background(NavBarAccessor { navBar in
            self.navBarHeight = navBar.bounds.height
        })
    }
```

For Reproducing(as close to how mine actual project is setup):

Content View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        DragImageView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

DragImageView:

```
import SwiftUI


struct DragImageView: View {
    
    //===================
    // MARK: Properties
    //===================

    @State private var addedImages = [UIImage?]()
    @State private var isShowPhotoLibrary = false
    @State private var image = UIImage()

    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            
            imageView
            
        }
        
        
        // Gets a new Image
        Button {
            self.isShowPhotoLibrary = true
            addedImages.append(image)

        } label: {
            Text("Add Image")
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary) {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: self.$image)
        }
        
       
        Spacer()

  
    }
    
    var imageView: some View {
        ZStack {
            DraggableImage(image: image)
        }
        //.clipped()
    }
    
    // This will dismiss the keyboard
    private func endEditing() {
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    }
}

// Allows fot the keyboard to be dismissed
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

DraggableImage:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DraggableImage: View {
    // Drag Gesture
    @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var newPosition: CGSize = .zero
    
    // Roation Gesture
    @State private var rotation: Double = 0.0
    
    // Scale Gesture
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    
    // The different states the frame of the label could be
    private enum WidthState: Int {
        case full, half, third, fourth
    }
    
    @State private var widthState: WidthState = .full
    @State private var currentWidth: CGFloat = 100 //UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    var image: UIImage
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: self.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: self.currentWidth)
                .lineLimit(nil)
        }
        .scaleEffect(scale) // Scale based on our state
        .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(rotation)) // Rotate based on the state
        .offset(x: self.currentPosition.width, // Offset from the drag difference from it's current position
                y: self.currentPosition.height)
        .gesture(
            
            // Two finger rotation
            RotationGesture()
                .onChanged { angle in
                    self.rotation = angle.degrees // keep track of the angle for state
                }
                // We want it to work with the scale effect, so they could either scale and rotate at the same time
                .simultaneously(with:
                                    MagnificationGesture()
                                    .onChanged { scale in
                                        self.scale = scale.magnitude // Keep track of the scale
                                    })
                // Update the drags new position to be wherever it was last dragged to. (we don't want to reset it back to it's current position)
                .simultaneously(with: DragGesture()
                                    .onChanged { value in
                                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width,
                                                                      height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                                    }
                                    .onEnded { value in
                                        self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                                    })
        )
        
        /// Have to do double tap first or else it will never work with the single tap
        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
            // Update our widthState to be the next on in the 'enum', or start back at .full
            self.widthState = WidthState(rawValue: self.widthState.rawValue + 1) ?? .full
            self.currentWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(self.widthState.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

ImagePicker:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = image
            }
            
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

I should add this is to make memes, so the user picked images go on top the view that I save to the camera roll.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried with the array? You'll definitely need an array and a `ForEach` like you're using for the `addedLabels`

Comment: Yes, I will show you the most recent way using the same button.

Comment: You didn't show all your code in your edit. Where you do define `addedImages`?

Comment: Sorry about, I have added it now.

Comment: Where is `memeImageView` called? Can you make a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I will add the body, hold on.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not runnable code for someone else -- it includes a bunch of stuff you haven't included. Create a blank project and create a minimal, reproducible example of it. Without that, it's going to be hard to get reliable advice about how to solve your issue.

Comment: Okay give me a few minutes.

Comment: Done! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what the exact desired output should be, but this should get you started (explained below):

```
struct DragImageView: View {
    
    //===================
    // MARK: Properties
    //===================

    @State private var addedImages = [UIImage]()
    @State private var isShowPhotoLibrary = false

    var bindingForImage: Binding<UIImage> {
        Binding<UIImage> { () -> UIImage in
            return addedImages.last ?? UIImage()
        } set: { (newImage) in
            addedImages.append(newImage)
            print("Images: \(addedImages.count)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            imageView
        }
        
        // Gets a new Image
        Button {
            self.isShowPhotoLibrary = true
        } label: {
            Text("Add Image")
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary) {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: bindingForImage)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
    var imageView: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(addedImages, id: \.self) { image in
                DraggableImage(image: image)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // This will dismiss the keyboard
    private func endEditing() {
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    }
}
```

`addedImages` is now an array of non-optional `UIImages`

There's a custom Binding for the image picker. When it receives a new image, it appends it to the end of the array.

In `var imageView`, there's a `VStack` instead of a `ZStack` so that multiple images can get displayed (instead of stacked on top of each other) and a `ForEach` loop to iterate through the images.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I owe you! That is exactly what I was trying to do!